# iOS - navigation controller back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm developing an iPad App using storyboards. In this app when the user click on "preferences" appear a modal View. One button of this view send the user to another View Controller (but this view has an action bar to go back to his root view controller), but when user taps the action bar back button nothing happen (it's called navigationController popViewControllerAnimated), the user continue in the same view.

Can anyone help me??

Thanks.

UPDATE:

The code to handle the back button:

```
- (IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I'm using Segue (from storyboard) to call this View Controller:

When the user click on "Meus Favoritos"

[image]

They will be redirect to this page:

[image]

The segue is with a Modal (from image one to two)...

Comment: Please post code and elaborate. Are you using a segue in the storyboard or are your using code to handle the button press?

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to work out what the problem is. However, my wild stab in the dark is that you are not pushing the last view controller properly onto the stack.

Comment: When you are presenting a View Controller modally, it is likely not within a navigationController, so probably the reference to `navigationController` is `nil`.

Comment: @Theopile, i'm using code to handle the button press: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are presenting a View Controller modally, it is likely not within a Navigation Controller, so probably the reference to `navigationController` in your code is `nil`, can you check that?

If you are presenting your View Controller modally this will work instead

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, if you actually want to use a Navigation Controller, you should embed the View Controller that is presenting the Preferences View Controller in a Navigation Controller and present the Preferences View Controller with a `show` segue instead of a `modal` one.

Comment: @Beng-G, many thanks you are right! navigationController is nil and dismissViewControllerAnimated work perfectly for me.... many thanks guys!